# Retrieving security alerts using rest api

Tags: github, curl, github-api

I am following the indications mentioned [here](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/code-scanning#list-code-scanning-alerts-for-an-organization), trying to retrieve the alerts but I always get a return error of 404, even though I am an owner in my organization. When I try to the same but for a public repo in the organization, it works as expected.
I’ve tried re-authenticating my self, create a new Personal Access token and pass it in the header, but still I get a 404. Am I missing something?

```
  curl \                                                                                                                           
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" \
  https://api.github.com/orgs/<OrgName>/code-scanning/alerts
```

With thepersonal access token in the request: `-H 'Authorization: token <My_Token>'` but I get the same exact message.

```
{
  "message": "Not Found",
  "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/rest/reference/code-scanning#list-code-scanning-alerts-by-organization"
}
```

Also tried it using the github cli which already has me authenticated
Did I find a bug?

Comment: GitHub returning a 404 is most likely an issue with the authorisation. try `curl -u <myusername>:<mytoken> ... rest of request` -- the personal access token in it's own header I think is for when you're doing the whole Oauth workflow.

Comment: Nop, same error

Comment: Does your token have the `security_events` read permission?

Comment: yes it does. I went back after my initial token failing, and created one with full permissions

Comment: @MiguelLuís I am facing same issue. Were you able to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue as well. Reached out to GH support and this was their response:

> At this time this is expected (but undocumented) behavior. This end point is currently only available for organizations with a GitHub Advanced Security license.
> Our engineers are working on making this functionality available for all users, but there is not currently an estimate for when this will be released.

Hopefully they roll this out to all users soon.